# Running safariwatir against watirspec

Tags: ruby, watir, safariwatir

I am following *Running safariwatir against watirspec* instructions from safariwatir [readme](https://github.com/redsquirrel/safariwatir).

```
$ git clone git://github.com/redsquirrel/safariwatir.git
Cloning into safariwatir...
...

$ cd safariwatir

$ git submodule update --init
Submodule 'spec/watirspec' (git://github.com/jarib/watirspec.git) registered for path 'spec/watirspec'
Cloning into spec/watirspec...
...
Submodule path 'spec/watirspec': checked out '4e080506694b079d08135e610716e5655f07183f'
```

Since I have rspec 2, I have replaced `spec spec` with `rspec spec`:

```
$ rspec spec
/Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /Users/zeljko/Documents/projekt/safariwatir/spec/watirspec/lib/server.rb:91: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
...
```

As [jarib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199912/jarib) said in his answer, safariwatir's watirspec points to and old commit ([4e08](https://github.com/jarib/watirspec/commit/4e080506694b079d08135e610716e5655f07183f) from 2009), so I have updated it to point to the latest commit in watir2 branch of watirspec.

```
$ cd spec/watirspec && git pull origin watir2
From git://github.com/jarib/watirspec
 * branch            watir2     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 4e08050..fa27ccf
...
```

safariwatir's watirspec now points to fa27ccf, but `rspec spec` now complains that it could not find `spec/implementation.rb` file.

```
$ rspec spec
/Users/zeljko/Documents/projekt/safariwatir/spec/watirspec/lib/runner.rb:58:in `load': no such file to load -- /Users/zeljko/Documents/projekt/safariwatir/spec/implementation.rb (LoadError)
```

I have created `spec/implementation.rb` file according to instructions from watirspec readme and by reading [watir](https://github.com/bret/watir/blob/master/spec/implementation.rb), [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/blob/master/spec/implementation.rb) and [celerity](https://github.com/jarib/celerity/blob/master/spec/implementation.rb) `implementation.rb` file.

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift("../lib")
require "safariwatir"

include Watir::Exception

WatirSpec.implementation do |imp|
  imp.name = :safariwatir
  imp.browser_class = Watir::Safari
end
```

Finally it works:

```
$ rspec spec
...
Finished in 27.89 seconds
1005 examples, 997 failures
```

99% of failures look like this:

```
  10) Browser#html returns the DOM of the page as an HTML string
     Failure/Error: browser.goto(WatirSpec.files + "/right_click.html")
     Appscript::CommandError:
       CommandError
            OSERROR: -609
            MESSAGE: Connection is invalid.
            COMMAND: app("/Applications/Safari.app").documents[1].URL.set("file:///Users/zeljko/Documents/projekt/safariwatir/spec/watirspec/html/right_click.html")
     # ./lib/safariwatir/scripter.rb:253:in `block in navigate_to'
     # ./lib/safariwatir/scripter.rb:697:in `page_load'
     # ./lib/safariwatir/scripter.rb:252:in `navigate_to'
     # ./lib/safariwatir.rb:960:in `goto'
     # ./spec/watirspec/browser_spec.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Environment:

Mac OS X 10.6.8, Safari 5.1.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
rspec (2.6.0)
...
rubygems-update (1.8.7)
...
safariwatir (0.4.0)
```

Comment: Issues like this make me wonder how far the Webdriver people are from Safari support.  While I'd never use it personally due to a poor security track record (FF or Chrome would be better) there are hundreds of thousand of users who drink the apple-Koolaide and can't be bothered to change browsers, so as testers, we need to test against it if Mac users are important to us.

Comment: I do not think webdriver will have support for Safari any time soon.

Comment: Anything in particular that makes you think that?  is it something the Selenium crowd has against apple, or apple being their usually unhelpful self? or something else?

Comment: I think Jari said something like "we are waiting for Apple to step up". :)

Comment: great.. ok so they took like 4 years to even start to patch security issues with safari, even after being embarrassed as 'first to fall' at events like PWN2OWN for year after year..   so I guess based on that kind of response time track record, 2014 if we are lucky... great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be running `rspec spec` (the spec binary seems to point to your non-RVM Ruby install in /Library/...).

The encoding issue was fixed [here](https://github.com/jarib/watirspec/commit/cfc589096b3d05ea10136ac2f052bd1cb9816bf3) - so safariwatir's watirspec submodule is quite outdated. Either update the submodule, or use 1.8.7 to avoid the problem.

Comment: I have done `git submodule update --init` while adding watirspec submodule, and `git submodule update` now does not do anything. I guess watirspec is up to date, right? Should I change something in `.gitmodules`? How to update watirspec?

Comment: If you want watirspec master: `cd spec/watirspec && git pull origin master`. watir-webdriver and watir is using the watir2 branch of watirspec, so if you want that, replace 'master' with 'watir2' in the pull command. Then 'cd ../..' and commit the submodule change.

Comment: tried running `rspec spec` from ruby 1.8.7, but still no luck

Comment: thanks, I did not use submodules so far, so I am a bit confused, will try updating

Comment: if both watir and watir-webdriver are using watir2 branch, why is it not merged to master? Who is using master then?

Comment: Problems again: `git pull origin watir2` says `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref watir2`.

Comment: As suggested at https://twitter.com/#!/charley_baker/status/100581801210298368 I have tried to run `spec spec` with rspec 1.3.1 and it works. At least something is moving forward.

Comment: `git pull origin watir2` now works fine. Updated to `698e6a3`.